# Google Calendar API - cronjob

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, cron-task

I want to develop a cronjob program to communicate via GCal API.
I have several events owned by users. Every night it must sync events to private calendars of each one. 
The problem exists because to use OAuth authentication users must grant permission to every day.
I read that OAuth has refresh tokens. There is not a solution to me because I can't refresh thousands of users constantly, it will cause lots of requests and it is not the best solution. 
Is there a way to call the API or any other option to do this kind of sync?

Comment: To access the API programatically like this without manual login by each user, you will require a Service Account for each user's Google Account which you need to interact with. The user will have to configure it and provide you with the detail. Alternatively, if you're using G-suite, the domain administrator can grant to third party applications domain-wide access to its users' data using a single Service Account. See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: Hi ADyson, i read this alternative. The problem is i don't control the users. I will have a range of more than 8 million users. They will configure events in my app and after that the sync with calendar. They will not have a connection to any Service Account, they are normal accounts of general users.
I can't use G-Suite either because the accounts are not users of any Service account.

Comment: In that case I think you cannot achieve your requirement like this. If each user logs in with your app, you must get them to authenticate their google account while using your app, and if they manipulate an event in your app, you immediately call the Google API to insert/update/delete the event there as well, in real time. You cannot realistically do any kind of batch processing in the way you're describing without a service account. Even if you used refresh tokens it's not indefinite - eventually Google would require the user to re-authenticate, and the cron service would fail for that user.

Comment: However " I can't use G-Suite either because the accounts are not users of any Service account." - this does not make sense. If the users are all members of your G-Suite domain, the point is you can create _one_ service account to access _all_ the user accounts. But if you are saying that these are general Google users, not within a G-Suite domain, then this situation does not apply. I just wanted to clarify your understanding though, because lack of service accounts is not the reason you can't use G-Suite. Not being a G-Suite customer would be the reason for that.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Your last suggestion could be a solution, but in my case i will have also automatic changes from other systems so is not a perfect match.

Comment: well the app would have to load those changes from their source when it starts, and then upload them to the user's google calendar at that same moment.

Comment: Another potential alternative is simply to provide an iCalendar (.ics) feed URL, and get the users to subscribe to it, so it shows alongside their own calendar events. This also has the advantage of not restricting your user base to Google Calendar users - many other calendar programs and services also understand that format. I don't know if that suits your use case but it's worth considering.

Comment: All users will have General Google Accounts and won't be under a G-Suite domain. So i can't use that approach.
I can't use URL feed because for that i would have a remote public url for each user and this is not a option, because i can't have public remote information about any person. This is a limitation we have according to portuguese personal data laws. It was one of my suggestions to solve this problem and it was not accepted.

Comment: "well the app would have to load those changes from their source when it starts, and then upload them to the user's google calendar at that same moment"..
i can't make this kind of approach because users will have really important data across the application and they can't miss some type of events just because they don't log regularly on the app. The goal of the solution is to have a configuration that gave them auto info and not to log every day. The best solution for the sync with calendars would be assyncronous process, but i'm getting that it would not be possible.

Comment: I tried also caldav library and ical libraries for java, but both cases require user clear text password, and is really a dangerous request, so i tried gcal api....

Comment: " both cases require user clear text password". No idea what you mean by this. If you publish your app's calendar data via CalDAV or via an ICS feed, you can put whatever authentication and encryption you like on it. You could use OAuth and HTTPS if you wanted. I don't see what impact a code library has on that.

Comment: I mean those two libraries i try to use require authentication like that. it was not google apis or libraries, i just pronounced other kind of approaches i tried before, it was not the remote url.
It was those libs: 
* https://github.com/caldav4j/caldav4j
* https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j

Comment: This one: https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j has nothing at all to do with passwords as far as I can see, It just generates ICS data. You can host, secure and encrypt that resulting data however you choose. This one https://github.com/caldav4j/caldav4j contains an example using HTTPS, and I'm fairly sure that's not the only way you can supply credentials to a calDAV instance anyway, if it complies with the calDAV protocol.

Comment: I find a solution to user Google API. I will save the consent of each user in my UI. After that my process will read those files for each user and use the saved authorization. It will be simpler to do and will work across all my requirements.